Drawing waves using tikz in latex
I am trying to reproduce this figure :

But the best I can do is this output :

I would like to emphasize on the "wave" effect to have more place for putting clear labels...
Any tips to do so ?
Thank you for your contribution,
Code :
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

%%%% SCHEMA TIKZ POUR RAYLEIGH TAYLOR %%%%%
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=-1]
% Define colors
\definecolor{filmColor}{rgb}{0.5, 0.7, 0.9}
\definecolor{plateColor}{rgb}{0.3, 0.3, 0.3}
\definecolor{elasticFilmColor}{rgb}{1.0, 0.4, 0.7}
% Plate
\fill[plateColor] (0,0) rectangle (10,0.5);
% Film
\fill[filmColor] (0,0.5) -- (0,1.5) .. controls (1,1.7) and (2,1.3) .. (3,1.5) .. controls (4,1.7) and (5,1.3) .. (6,1.5) .. controls (7,1.7) and (8,1.3) .. (9,1.5) -- (10,1.5) -- (10,0.5) -- cycle;
\draw[stealth-stealth,red,thin] (9.5, 0.5) -- (9.5, 1.5) node[pos=0.5,left] {$h_0$};
\draw[stealth-stealth,red,thin] (6.7, 0.5) -- (6.7, 1.55) node[pos=0.5,left] {$h(x,t)$};
\draw[stealth-stealth,red,thin] (3.7, 1.65) -- (6.7, 1.65) node[pos=0.5,below] {$\lambda$};
\draw[dashed,black,very thin] (0, 1.5) -- (9.5, 1.5);
% Axes and labels
\draw[-stealth,red,thick] (0, 0.5) -- (0, 2) node[left] {$e_y$};
\draw[-stealth,red,thick] (0, 0.5) -- (11, 0.5) node[below] {$e_x$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}


You could use a path decoration to draw the wave effect. This way you can easily change the amplitude:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}

%%%% SCHEMA TIKZ POUR RAYLEIGH TAYLOR %%%%%
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=-1]
% Define colors
\definecolor{filmColor}{rgb}{0.5, 0.7, 0.9}
\definecolor{plateColor}{rgb}{0.3, 0.3, 0.3}
\definecolor{elasticFilmColor}{rgb}{1.0, 0.4, 0.7}
% Plate
\fill[plateColor] (0,0) rectangle (10.5,0.5);
% Film
\fill[filmColor] (0,0.5) -- (0,1.5) decorate [decoration={coil,aspect=0,amplitude=0.5cm,segment length=3cm}] {-- (10.5,1.5)} -- (10.5,0.5) -- cycle;
\draw[stealth-stealth,red,thin] (9.75, 0.5) -- (9.75, 1.5) node[pos=0.5,left] {$h_0$};
\draw[stealth-stealth,red,thin] (6, 0.5) -- (6, 1.5) node[pos=0.5,left] {$h(x,t)$};
\draw[stealth-stealth,red,thin] (5.25, 2) -- (8.25, 2) node[pos=0.5,below] {$\lambda$};
\draw[dashed,black,very thin] (0, 1.5) -- (10.5, 1.5);
%% Axes and labels
\draw[-stealth,red,thick] (0, 0.5) -- (0, 2) node[left] {$e_y$};
\draw[-stealth,red,thick] (0, 0.5) -- (11, 0.5) node[below] {$e_x$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}


Or you could plot an actual function:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

%%%% SCHEMA TIKZ POUR RAYLEIGH TAYLOR %%%%%
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=-1]
% Define colors
\definecolor{filmColor}{rgb}{0.5, 0.7, 0.9}
\definecolor{plateColor}{rgb}{0.3, 0.3, 0.3}
\definecolor{elasticFilmColor}{rgb}{1.0, 0.4, 0.7}
% Plate
\fill[plateColor] (0,0) rectangle (10.5,0.5);
% Film
\fill[filmColor] (0,0.5) -- (0,1.5) -- plot[domain=0:10.5,samples=100] (\x,{1.5-0.5*sin(2*3.1415*\x r/3)}) -- (10.5,1.5) -- (10.5,0.5) -- cycle;
\draw[stealth-stealth,red,thin] (9.75, 0.5) -- (9.75, 1.5) node[pos=0.5,left] {$h_0$};
\draw[stealth-stealth,red,thin] (6, 0.5) -- (6, 1.5) node[pos=0.5,left] {$h(x,t)$};
\draw[stealth-stealth,red,thin] (5.25, 2) -- (8.25, 2) node[pos=0.5,below] {$\lambda$};
\draw[dashed,black,very thin] (0, 1.5) -- (10.5, 1.5);
%% Axes and labels
\draw[-stealth,red,thick] (0, 0.5) -- (0, 2) node[left] {$e_y$};
\draw[-stealth,red,thick] (0, 0.5) -- (11, 0.5) node[below] {$e_x$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}


